# Regular expression: how to match a string containing "\n" (newline)?

Tags: python, regex, escaping, line-breaks

I'm trying to dump data from a SQL export file with regular expression. To match the field of post content, I use '`(?P<content>.*?)`'. It works fine most of the time, but if the field contains the string of '\n' the regular expression wouldn't match. How can I modify the regular expression to match them? Thanks!

Example(I'm using Python):

```
>>> re.findall("'(?P<content>.*?)'","'<p>something, something else</p>'")
['<p>something, something else</p>']

>>> re.findall("'(?P<content>.*?)'","'<p>something, \n something else</p>'")
[]
```

P.S. Seemingly all strings with '\' in the front are treated as escape characters. How can I tell regx to treat them as they are?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should use `DOTALL` option:

```
>>> re.findall("'(?P<content>.*?)'","'<p>something, \n something else</p>'", re.DOTALL)
['<p>something, \n something else</p>']
```

See [this](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).

Comment: Thanks! Also, just for example, if I have say '\a' in the string, it will be converted to '\x07'. Is there a way to keep them as they are? Or if it doesn't matter when I put them into the database?

Comment: `\x07` is just a way for python to represent the character with code 7. Another way to represent it is to write `\a`. The string actually contains just a single character in both cases. You can confirm this by checking `len("\x07")` and `len("\a")`. Also try comparing `"\a" == "\x07"` or searching for `"a"` in `"\a"`: `"\a".find("a")` or for `"0"` in `"\x07"`: `"\x07".find("0")`. Results should be very informative.

Comment: Hi Adam! It's still posing a problem, if the origin string contains \' The result will be converted to ', which will break the sql commands. So it is important to have the string "as it is"

Answer (score 4):

You need the Dotall modifier, to make the dot also match newline characters.

> re.S
>   re.DOTALL
>   Make the '.' special character match any character at
>   all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything
>   except a newline.

See it [here on docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)