# Extract YAML headers using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a file with YAML headers, that is a file with starts with `---`, have `---`. Something like:

```
---
title: Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?
author: Dan Meyer
date: 2013-08-26
abstract: Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?
tags: 3-acts
continguts: àrea, cercle, ajustament de corbes, extrapolació, funció quadràtica, representació de funcions, 
relatedto: []
lang: ca
---


[![Penny circle](./shot.png)](http://threeacts.mrmeyer.com/pennycircle/)

Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?

## Recursos ##

1. [Proposta original d'en Dan Meyer](http://blog.mrmeyer.com/2013/makeover-penny-circle/) ([localment](./media/activitats/meyer-penny-circle/dy_dan » Blog Archive » [Makeover] Penny Circle.htm))
1. L'[activitat en tres actes](http://threeacts.mrmeyer.com/pennycircle/) d'en Dan Meyer ([localment](./media/activitats/meyer-penny-circle/pennycircle.zip))
1. [Activitat a Desmos](https://teacher.desmos.com/pennycircle)
```

I want to use regular expressions in python3 to split the contents: YAML contents and the rest of the file. In my example, the first part is this

```
---
title: Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?
author: Dan Meyer
date: 2013-08-26
abstract: Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?
tags: 3-acts
continguts: àrea, cercle, ajustament de corbes, extrapolació, funció quadràtica, representació de funcions, 
relatedto: []
lang: ca
---
```

And the second that:

```
[![Penny circle](./shot.png)](http://threeacts.mrmeyer.com/pennycircle/)

Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?

## Recursos ##

1. [Proposta original d'en Dan Meyer](http://blog.mrmeyer.com/2013/makeover-penny-circle/) ([localment](./media/activitats/meyer-penny-circle/dy_dan » Blog Archive » [Makeover] Penny Circle.htm))
1. L'[activitat en tres actes](http://threeacts.mrmeyer.com/pennycircle/) d'en Dan Meyer ([localment](./media/activitats/meyer-penny-circle/pennycircle.zip))
1. [Activitat a Desmos](https://teacher.desmos.com/pennycircle)
```

I use this re: `p = re.compile('---\n(.*?)\n---\n(.*?)')` but it does not work.

Comment: yaml content can be found **[using](https://regex101.com/r/sJ1uC6/1)**

Comment: @rock321987: why omit the newlines?

Comment: @MartijnPieters newlines??didn't get your point?

Comment: @rock321987: you omitted the `\n` after the `---` line. So `---foobar` also matches now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters didn't noticed..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression: how to match a string containing "\n" (newline)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150745/regular-expression-how-to-match-a-string-containing-n-newline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` does not match newlines, unless you set the [`DOTALL` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.S):

```
p = re.compile('---\n(.*?)\n---\n(.*)', flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Note that I dropped the `?` from the second `*`; you'd want everything after the second `---`, not just the first 1 character.

From the documentation:

> `re.S`
>   `re.DOTALL`
>   Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, `'.'` will match anything except a newline.

However, you could just split your text on the `---\n` line; limit it to two splits:

```
yaml, text = text.split('---\n', 2)[1:]
```

This splits your text into a prefix, the YAML section, and the rest. The prefix is ignored with `[1:]`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('---\n(.*?)\n---\n(.*)', flags=re.DOTALL)
>>> p.search(text).groups()
('title: Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?\nauthor: Dan Meyer\ndate: 2013-08-26\nabstract: Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?\ntags: 3-acts\ncontinguts: àrea, cercle, ajustament de corbes, extrapolació, funció quadràtica, representació de funcions, \nrelatedto: []\nlang: ca', "\n\n[![Penny circle](./shot.png)](http://threeacts.mrmeyer.com/pennycircle/)\n\nQuantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?\n\n## Recursos ##\n\n1. [Proposta original d'en Dan Meyer](http://blog.mrmeyer.com/2013/makeover-penny-circle/) ([localment](./media/activitats/meyer-penny-circle/dy_dan » Blog Archive » [Makeover] Penny Circle.htm))\n1. L'[activitat en tres actes](http://threeacts.mrmeyer.com/pennycircle/) d'en Dan Meyer ([localment](./media/activitats/meyer-penny-circle/pennycircle.zip))\n1. [Activitat a Desmos](https://teacher.desmos.com/pennycircle)\n")
>>> text.split('---\n', 2)[1:]
['title: Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?\nauthor: Dan Meyer\ndate: 2013-08-26\nabstract: Quantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?\ntags: 3-acts\ncontinguts: àrea, cercle, ajustament de corbes, extrapolació, funció quadràtica, representació de funcions, \nrelatedto: []\nlang: ca\n', "\n\n[![Penny circle](./shot.png)](http://threeacts.mrmeyer.com/pennycircle/)\n\nQuantes monedes de cèntim caben a un cercle?\n\n## Recursos ##\n\n1. [Proposta original d'en Dan Meyer](http://blog.mrmeyer.com/2013/makeover-penny-circle/) ([localment](./media/activitats/meyer-penny-circle/dy_dan » Blog Archive » [Makeover] Penny Circle.htm))\n1. L'[activitat en tres actes](http://threeacts.mrmeyer.com/pennycircle/) d'en Dan Meyer ([localment](./media/activitats/meyer-penny-circle/pennycircle.zip))\n1. [Activitat a Desmos](https://teacher.desmos.com/pennycircle)\n"]
```

Answer (score 2):

For such a simple delimiter, you don't really need regular expressions. Given test file...

```
---
This is the first part
---
This is the second part
```

...something as simple as...

```
>>> s = open('testfile').read()
>>> _, part1, part2 = s.split('---\n')
>>> print part1
This is the first part

>>> print part2
This is the second part
```

...should suffice.